# Getting information about a DOM element with WebDriver

Tags: python, webdriver

I have an element `myElement` (found using `.find_element_by_class_name()`). Now when I print

```
print myElement
```

I only get

```
<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement ojbect at 0x10ca04510>
```

How can I know more information about that element, such as `id`, `tag`, `class`, etc.?

[I've also tried `dir(myElement)`.]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supported by WebDriver; if you know the attribute name(s), you can use `get_attribute(name)` but there is no way to list all attributes of a `WebElement`.

[Watij](http://watij.com/) has the same problems. It seems that all such web testing frameworks are only useful if you don't use HTML5 - that is pages which rely heavily on JavaScript, AJAX, which assign dynamic IDs to elements or no IDs at all, they don't get much love from these frameworks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `print dir(myElement)`?

That will show all variables and methods to that object. Just skip over everything that starts with an underscore.

Comment: Aha, thanks. Although I'm looking for something closer to what happens when you dump a DOM element in the JavaScript console in Google Chrome.

Comment: Ok, can't help you with that. I'm not familiar with the selenium. Just figured you missed `print`(which you don't need if writting directly in the interpreter).  ;)